# Use dynamically generated column names in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a data frame with multiple columns, the user provides a vector with the column names, and I want to count maximum amount of times an element appears

```
set.seed(42)
df <- tibble(
  var1 = sample(c(1:3),10,replace=T),
  var2 = sample(c(1:3),10,replace=T),
  var3 = sample(c(1:3),10,replace=T)
)
select_vars <- c("var1", "var3")

df %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(consensus=max(table(unlist(c(var1,var3)))))

# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Rowwise: 
    var1  var2  var3 consensus
   <int> <int> <int>     <int>
 1     1     1     1         2
 2     1     1     3         1
 3     1     2     1         2
 4     1     2     1         2
 5     2     2     2         2
 6     2     3     3         1
 7     2     3     2         2
 8     1     1     1         2
 9     3     1     2         1
10     3     3     2         1
```

This does exactly what I want, but when I try to use a vector of variables i cant get it to work

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(consensus=max(unlist(table(select_vars)) )))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OP's code, we need `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(consensus=max(table(unlist(select(cur_data(), select_vars))) ))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Rowwise: 
    var1  var2  var3 consensus
   <int> <int> <int>     <int>
 1     1     1     1         2
 2     1     1     3         1
 3     1     2     1         2
 4     1     2     1         2
 5     2     2     2         2
 6     2     3     3         1
 7     2     3     2         2
 8     1     1     1         2
 9     3     1     2         1
10     3     3     2         1
```

---

Or just subset from `cur_data()` which would only return the data keeping the group attributes

```
df %>%
     rowwise %>% 
     mutate(consensus = max(table(unlist(cur_data()[select_vars]))))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Rowwise: 
    var1  var2  var3 consensus
   <int> <int> <int>     <int>
 1     1     1     1         2
 2     1     1     3         1
 3     1     2     1         2
 4     1     2     1         2
 5     2     2     2         2
 6     2     3     3         1
 7     2     3     2         2
 8     1     1     1         2
 9     3     1     2         1
10     3     3     2         1
```

---

Or using `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
df %>%
     mutate(consensus = pmap_dbl(cur_data()[select_vars], ~ max(table(c(...)))))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    var1  var2  var3 consensus
   <int> <int> <int>     <dbl>
 1     1     1     1         2
 2     1     1     3         1
 3     1     2     1         2
 4     1     2     1         2
 5     2     2     2         2
 6     2     3     3         1
 7     2     3     2         2
 8     1     1     1         2
 9     3     1     2         1
10     3     3     2         1
```

---

As these are rowwise operations, can get some efficiency if we use `collapse` functions

```
library(collapse)
tfm(df, consensus = dapply(slt(df, select_vars), MARGIN = 1,
       FUN = function(x) fmax(tabulate(x))))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    var1  var2  var3 consensus
 * <int> <int> <int>     <int>
 1     1     1     1         2
 2     1     1     3         1
 3     1     2     1         2
 4     1     2     1         2
 5     2     2     2         2
 6     2     3     3         1
 7     2     3     2         2
 8     1     1     1         2
 9     3     1     2         1
10     3     3     2         1
```

#### Benchmarks

As noted above, `collapse` is faster (run on a slightly bigger dataset)

```
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 1e5), ]

system.time({
tfm(df1, consensus = dapply(slt(df1, select_vars), MARGIN = 1,
       FUN = function(x) fmax(tabulate(x))))

})
#user  system elapsed 
#  5.257   0.123   5.323 

system.time({
df1 %>%
     mutate(consensus = pmap_dbl(cur_data()[select_vars], ~ max(table(c(...)))))

})
#user  system elapsed 
# 54.813   0.517  55.246
```

The `rowwise` operation is taking too much time, so stopped the execution

```
df1 %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(consensus=max(table(unlist(select(cur_data(), select_vars))) ))
 })
Timing stopped at: 575.5 3.342 581.3
```

Comment: somehow this is not working since all values are 1

Comment: @JorgeKageyama Your example is not reprodcuible as there is no `set.seed`

Comment: thnx for the comment, ill set a seed, but still jsut from the output is clear that all values in consensus are 1, and that cant be right

Comment: @JorgeKageyama i think you just need to wrap the `unlist` inside the `table`.  updated

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap it in  `c(!!! syms())` to get it working, and you don't need the `unlist` apparently. But honestly, I'm not sure what you are trying to do, and why `table` is needed here. Do you just want to check if `var2` and `var3` are the same value and if then `2` and if not then `1`?

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(
  var1 = sample(c(1:3),10,replace=T),
  var2 = sample(c(1:3),10,replace=T),
  var3 = sample(c(1:3),10,replace=T)
)

select_vars <- c("var2", "var3")

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(consensus=max(table(c(!!!syms(select_vars)))))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>     var1  var2  var3 consensus
#>    <int> <int> <int>     <int>
#>  1     2     3     2         1
#>  2     3     1     3         1
#>  3     3     1     1         2
#>  4     3     3     3         2
#>  5     1     1     2         1
#>  6     2     1     3         1
#>  7     3     2     3         1
#>  8     1     2     3         1
#>  9     2     1     2         1
#> 10     2     1     1         2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That is not working, all numbers in consensus are one, the second row in consensus should be 2

Comment: this is a toy example, this is used to calculate some statistics tables based on the overlap of over-expressed genes.

Comment: @JorgeKageyama: Oh I see. If its a lot of data I'd follow akruns recommendation and look at `pmax` instead of using `rowwise`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the verb `all_of`

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(consensus=max(table(unlist(all_of(select_vars)))))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Rowwise: 
    var1  var2  var3 consensus
   <int> <int> <int>     <int>
 1     2     3     3         1
 2     2     2     2         1
 3     1     2     2         1
 4     2     3     3         1
 5     1     2     1         1
 6     2     1     2         1
 7     2     2     2         1
 8     3     1     2         1
 9     2     1     3         1
10     3     2     1         1
```

Comment: this is not working, all the values in consensus are 1, in the example i set the seed to make it preduicible, but look at row 2, all the values are the same, but according to this the maximum number of occurences is 1